# Java ImageIO Class Drawing Image and Saving as TIFF

Tags: java, javax.imageio

Java 1.8_201 on Windows 7 (32 bit)
Below is my code. I can't attach the image since TIFF is not a supported format.
I don't understand why the TIFF image I create has reversed the colors.
The JPEG images seem OK.
According to Windows Photo Viewer, the images have the following properties:

back.tif

width = 1337 pixels

height = 712 pixels

horizontal resolution = 200 dpi

vertical resolution = 200 dpi

bit depth = 1

compression = CCITT T.6

Similar for file front.tif

both.tif

width = 1340 pixels

height = 1425 pixels

horizontal resolution = 1 dpi

vertical resolution 1 dpi

bit depth = 1

compression = uncompressed

back2.jpg

width = 1337 pixels

height = 712 pixels

horizontal resolution = 200 dpi

vertical resolution = 200 dpi

bit depth = 8

(no compression details displayed)

both2.jpg

width = 1340 pixels

height = 1425 pixels

horizontal resolution = 96 dpi

vertical resolution = 96 dpi

bit depth = 8

(no compression details displayed)

My code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class TwoImage {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
//        File back = new File("C:\\temp\\back2.jpg");
        File front = new File("C:\\temp\\front.tif"); // width = 1340 , height = 713
//        File front = new File("C:\\temp\\front2.jpg");
        File back = new File("C:\\temp\\back.tif"); // width = 1337 , height = 712
        try {
            BufferedImage bImg = ImageIO.read(back);
            BufferedImage fImg = ImageIO.read(front);
            BufferedImage img2 = new BufferedImage(1340,
                                                   1425,
//                                                   BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
                                                   BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
            Graphics2D g2D = img2.createGraphics();
            g2D.drawImage(fImg, 0, 0, null);
            g2D.drawImage(bImg, 0, 713, null);
            g2D.dispose();
//            File output = new File("C:\\temp\\both2.jpg");
            File output = new File("C:\\temp\\both.tif");
//            ImageIO.write(img2, "JPEG", output);
            ImageIO.write(img2, "TIFF", output);
        }
        catch (Exception x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You must change the type of `BufferedImage` your create from `TYPE_BYTE_BINARY` to `TYPE_INT_ARGB` (or `TYPE_INT_RGB` if your images don't have alpha).
The type you use (`TYPE_BYTE_BINARY`) allows only 2 colors: Black and White.

Comment: @Nutriz, my TIFF images are black and white, i.e. binary images. By the way I already tried TYPE_INT_RGB and got the same result.

Comment: I tried with a colored image and a black/white one, and all works fine with your code, no reversed color. The only difference with yours sources files are the compression type (Adobe deflate and PackBits for me, CCITT T.6 for you). I guess the problem is here and/or in the `Exif.Image.PhotometricInterpretation` field, can be "Black is zero" or "White is zero", maybe in some part of the process, this value changed. Try with another compression format for the source files and also get a better image viewer to have complementary informations about the image format. With Gimp: Image>Metadata>View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a test program that loads one of the TIFF images and displays it as an Icon on a JLabel and that was displayed with reversed colors. Hence I assumed that the default TIFF image reader that comes with JDK 1.8.0_201 is not appropriate here. So I guessed that I probably need to change the default settings, probably via class 'javax.imageio.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageReadParam'. But then I discovered [TwelveMonkeys](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys) and its default TIFF image reader handled my TIFF images correctly and that's how I solved my problem.